# fetch unique data from one to many relationship in hql and apply limit

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two pojo's

```
Endeavor
{
private Integer id;
private EndeavorPlan currentlyActiveEndeavorPlan;
private Set<EndeavorPlan> endeavorPlans;
}

EndeavorPlan{
 private Integer id;
 private Endeavor endeavor;
 private Date creationTs;
 private String status;
}
```

Query:

If I have currentlyActiveEndeavorPlan in endeavor then return that against their endeavor else I want the oldest creationTs endeavorPlan against their endeavor who does not have "D" status. any suggestions????

```
I tried this hql query:
SELECT 
                    endeavor.id, COALESCE(endeavor.currentlyActiveEndeavorPlan.id,plans.id)
            FROM
                    Endeavor as endeavor,
             IN
                    (endeavor.endeavorPlans) as plans
            WHERE
                    plans.endeavor.id = endeavor.id
                    and plans.id in (
                            SELECT  
                                    ep.id
                            FROM 
                                    EndeavorPlan as ep
                            WHERE 
                                    ep.endeavor.id = endeavor.id
                                    and ep.status <> 'D'
                            ORDER BY
                                    ep.creationTs asc
                    )
                    and endeavor.id in (:endeavorIds)
            GROUP BY
                    endeavor.id,plans.id
```

but its giving me two or more endeavorPlans who have more than one EndeavorPlan in an Endeavor but I only want the oldest creationTs EndeavorPlan against their Endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand your use case, but it seems to me that what you want is a Top-N per category which can't be done efficiently with HQL yet because subqueries do not support limit/offset yet (this changes with Hibernate 6).

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Endeavor.class)
public interface EndeavorDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    EndeavorPlanDto getCurrentlyActiveEndeavorPlan();
    @Limit(limit = "1", orderBy = "creationTs ASC")
    @Mapping("endeavorPlans[status <> 'D']")
    EndeavorPlanDto getLatestEndeavorPlan();

    @EntityView(EndeavorPlan.class)
    interface EndeavorPlanDto {
        @IdMapping
        Integer getId();
        Date getCreationTs();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`EndeavorDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, EndeavorDto.class, id);`

This will create a SQL query similar to the following:

```
select e.id, ep1.id, ep1.creation_ts, ep2.id, ep2.creation_ts
from endeavor e
left join endeavor_plan ep1 on e.active_plan = ep1.id
left join lateral (
    select ep2.id, ep2.creation_ts
    from endeavor_plan ep2
    where ep2.endeavor = e.id
    order by ep2.creation_ts asc
    limit 1
) ep2 on 1=1
```

If your database does not support lateral joins, it will create a similar query involving a subquery in the ON clause.

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<EndeavorDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!